# Excel (.xls file) - 4 sheets not possible?

Tags: excel, powershell

need your help again!

This Script doesn't work. It works for the first 3 Sheets, but doesn't work for the last one. If I switch the itemnumber (eg. 3->4 and 4->3) the new 3 works and the new 4 does not. Is this some sort of bug? Or am I missing some commandlet to increase the "maximum sheet number"?

```
$Path     = "C:\test.xls"
#Excelvar:
    $Row                 = [int] 2
    $Excel               = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Excel.Visible       = $true
    $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
                #Sheets:
                $ADUsers     = "Active Directory Users"
                $Groups      = "Create Groups"
                $UsertoGroup = "User to groups"
                $DNS         = "DNS"
 #$Worksheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Add()
    $checkxls = test-path -pathtype Any $Path
       if ($checkxls -eq $false) {  
            $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()

            $ws1 = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
            $ws1.Name = $ADUsers
            $ws1.activate()
            $ws2 = $wb.Worksheets.Item(2)
            $ws2.Name = $Groups
            $ws2.activate()
            $ws3 = $wb.Worksheets.Item(3)
            $ws3.Name = $UserToGroup
            $ws3.activate()
            $ws4 = $wb.Worksheets.Item(4)
            $ws4.Name = $DNS
            $ws4.activate()

            $wb.SaveAs($Path)
            $wb.Close()
            $Excel.Quit()
```

Errorcode:

```
"Invalid Index. (Exception by HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))"
```

Thx for help in advance.

extra information:
using powershell 3.0
using excel 2010

Comment: Is it zero based? so 0 - 3 not 1 - 4

Comment: nope, same issue with 0. "Invalid Index. (Exception by HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))"
+                 $ws4 = $wb.Worksheets.Item(0)

Comment: Never worked with Powershell but here is my two cents... Based on your Excel settings a new workbook will have only 3 worksheets by default. You need to add and extra sheet if you want to work with it. Not sure if in Powershell you have a way to count the number of worksheets present. Once you get the count then based on that, you can add new worksheet.

Comment: @Siddharth I had the same conclusion, but I too have never worked with powershell before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you're refering to a different workbook

this line

```
  $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
```

implies you're working with a new workbook.

try adding

```
  $wb.Worksheets.Add()
```

after the workbook is created, and see if that works.

---

```
$Path     = "C:\test.xls"
#Excelvar:
$Row                 = [int] 2
$Excel               = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible       = $true
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
            #Sheets:
            $ADUsers     = "Active Directory Users"
            $Groups      = "Create Groups"
            $UsertoGroup = "User to groups"
            $DNS         = "DNS"
 #$Worksheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Add()
 $checkxls = test-path -pathtype Any $Path
   if ($checkxls -eq $false) {  
        $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()

             $wb.Worksheets.add()

        $ws1 = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
        $ws1.Name = $ADUsers
        $ws1.activate()
        $ws2 = $wb.Worksheets.Item(2)
        $ws2.Name = $Groups
        $ws2.activate()
        $ws3 = $wb.Worksheets.Item(3)
        $ws3.Name = $UserToGroup
        $ws3.activate()
        $ws4 = $wb.Worksheets.Item(4)
        $ws4.Name = $DNS
        $ws4.activate()

        $wb.SaveAs($Path)
        $wb.Close()
        $Excel.Quit()
```

Comment: +1 I too feel this is is the reason. :) Like I mentioned in my comment above "Not sure if in Powershell you have a way to count the number of worksheets present. Once you get the count then based on that, you can add new worksheet."

Comment: @Sam Ward  ... doesn't solve the problem.                          You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    +                 $wb.Sheets.Add()
    +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [],  RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: $wb.Sheets.count gets me 0 after the workbookcreation and it gets me 0 after the third sheet has been renamed.

Comment: tried it like this:                 `$wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()`
                `$wb.Sheets.Add()`

Comment: I just added a full example of what I believe will fix your issue. sorry I'm not familiar with Powershell syntax. The correct syntax for checking worksheet count is actually `$Workbook.Worksheets.Count` I believe.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40303/discussion-between-sam-ward-and-xxinvidiaxx)

Comment: Please remove the line: $wb.Sheets.Add() ... this doesn't do anything, and might be confusing if other users read that question.

Comment: I changed it to `$wb.Worksheets.add()` which is correct I believe

Answer (score 0):

Tried adding Sheet4 on excel and it is code is reading Sheet4 just fine

```
#Declare the file path and sheet name
$file = "C:\Documents\Folder\ExcelFile.xlsx" 
$sheetName = "Sheet1" 

#Create an instance of Excel.Application and Open Excel file
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file) 
$sheetCount = $workbook.Worksheets.Count
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
$sheet4 = $workbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet4")
Write-Host $sheetCount #sheet count is 4
$objExcel.Visible=$false 

#Count max row
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count 
#Declare the starting positions
$rowName,$colName = 1,1
$rowAge,$colAge = 1,2 
$rowCity,$colCity = 1,3 

#loop to get values and store it 
for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++)
{ 
$name = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowName+$i,$colName).text 
$age = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowAge+$i,$colAge).text 
$city = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowCity+$i,$colCity).text 

Write-Host ("My Name is: "+$name)
Write-Host ("My Age is: "+$age)
Write-Host ("I live in: "+$city)
}

#used $rowMax from Sheet1, you can declare a separate for Sheet4
for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++) 
{ 
$name = $sheet4.Cells.Item($rowName+$i,$colName).text 
$age = $sheet4.Cells.Item($rowAge+$i,$colAge).text 
$city = $sheet4.Cells.Item($rowCity+$i,$colCity).text 

Write-Host ("My Name is: "+$name)
Write-Host ("My Age is: "+$age)
Write-Host ("I live in: "+$city)
}
#close excel file
$objExcel.quit()
```

Pardon my example, just a noob script :)